# Can an entangled pair of qubits be created across a distance by using purely classical communication?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Can an entangled pair of qubits be created across a distance by using purely classical communication, i.e. without using quantum communication?

Comment: @zmunk, useful search terms to find explanations for why not might be "Resource theory of entanglement" or "Entanglement and LOCC operations"

Answer (score 1):

No. This is precisely the *definition* of entanglement: What cannot be created with local operations and classical communication.